# How to inegrate paypal with iphone?

Tags: iphone

I am trying to integrate paypal with iphone n i m getting the error related to .o files of mobile payment library..want to know the complete procedure for integating paypal with iphone..and i m trying dis coding for paypal

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [PayPal initializeWithAppID:@"APP-80W284485P519543T" forEnvironment:ENV_SANDBOX];
}


-(IBAction)payPal:(id)sender
{
    PayPal *payObject=[PayPal getInstance];
    PayPalPayment *obj=[[PayPalPayment alloc]init];
    obj.recipient=@"priyankasaroha@gmail.com";
    obj.paymentCurrency=@"USD";
    obj.description=@"Teddy Bear";
    obj.merchantName=@"Priyanka";
    obj.subTotal = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"10"];    
    [payObject checkoutWithPayment:obj];
}
```

Comment: what have you done so far? Post the relevant code you have. Post the error you're getting.

Comment: I can't actually tell from your question what error you're getting. And there's no "complete procedure"—tell us what you've tried in your app, post the relevant sections of your source code, and any error messages that you've received. Here are some other [suggestions on how to write a good question](http://www.tinyurl.com/so-hints/).